# MySQL exclude column from select when column is equal to a specfic value

Tags: mysql

I have a Select query that selects columns from a table where there id is a specific value, e.g.

```
SELECT ID, Col1, Col2 FROM table1 WHERE ID = 4;
```

Where Col2 is an Integer column. If Col2 is 0 I want to exclude it from the select. At least 1 row will be returned by the above.

So basically if Col2 is 0, Return ID and Col1, if it isn't 0, return all three.

Is there any way to do this in MySQL?

EDIT: I should have said exclude the value not the column.

Comment: You can't have different numbers of columns in different rows of results. The result of a query is a table, all rows are uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `CASE` (but you can't exclude *totally* the column from your result)

```
SELECT
   ID,
   Col1,
   CASE WHEN Col2 <> 0 THEN Col2 END as Col2
FROM table1
WHERE ID = 4
```

Comment: This will have `Col2 == NULL`, it won't exclude the column.

Comment: @Barmar I should have written it in my answer, you're right. But this is the closest way of doing what OP wants

Comment: I would probably use `ELSE ''`, so the column is blank instead of `NULL`.